# Who create Ajax (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML)?

Tags: ajax

Honestly, I cannot find out the trust-able source of who create Ajax.
I just know that It become more popular by Google in 2005.

Anyone could guide me please?

Comment: Microsoft. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#History_and_support

Comment: IE has a hard definition, while some of the other browsers are more 'loosy-goosy' on base concepts (less the js vulnerabilities)

Answer (score 0):

Techniques to call server side code from client side script existed before AJAX existed, for example using a Java applet or a hidden frame/iframe to make a request to the server.

The work on the XMLHTTPRequest object that is now used for AJAX calls was begun by Microsoft around 1999. Reference: [Wikipedia: XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)